How to use SetPlatformApplicationAttributes amazon SNS java
I am using amazon SNS for push notification service. However, I recently got message:

On Jun 20, 2023, Google deprecated FCM v1 APIs. Starting June 01, 2024, Google plans to remove the ability to send mobile push notifications via the legacy FCM v1 APIs. In order to avoid impact to your existing platform applications, we recommend that you plan and migrate them on or before June 01, 2024. To upgrade your application, you must provide Amazon SNS a private key file in JSON format. You can get the key file from the Firebase application console for your application. For more information on upgrading existing applications

I have upgraded the dependency of SNS from 1.12.500 to 1.12.723. There has also been mention of this message:

You can also upgrade your existing platform application to use token-based authentication. Once you provide a valid key file, Amazon SNS will switch your application from the legacy FCM API to the new HTTP v1 API.

Where shall I provide the  key file? I have key file. can you provide me details of migration or we can use old implementation and just upgrade the version and provide valid private key json file?
Upgraded version of SNS from 1.12.500 to 1.12.723.
